# Colored mainfont with fontspec in a textblock yields to pdf error with LuaLaTex

Tags: pdf, luatex, fontspec, textpos

When I (1) change the color of the mainfont with the fontspec package, (2) put some text in a textblock environment and (3) compile the document with LuaLaTex, the resulting pdf when opened with Adobe Reader 9 displays the following error message:

> An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page
>   correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to
>   correct the problem

The document opens correctly and looks all good. However, this error message is annoying and does not look very professional. When I remove the colour specification in \setmainfont options, the error disappears.

Here is a MWE. Also, notice how the hyphens are kept black, unlike the main body of the text which is correctly painted in red:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[overlay, absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[]{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Color = red]{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
    \begin{textblock}{5}(5, 5)
        LaTeX is a high-quality typesetting system; it includes features designed for the production of technical and scientific documentation. LaTeX is the de facto standard for the communication and publication of scientific documents.
    \end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

I'm working in TeXstudio 2.6.6. in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The compilation is done with the following command "lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex". The compilation ends without any error or warning.

Am I the only one experiencing this issue or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I can not reproduce the error with "LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014) (rev 4971)" and AR 9.5.5. Which version of LuaTeX do you use? But the hyphens are black.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Thanks for your comment, it will help me narrow down the issue. I am using "LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013121407 (rev 4627)". I will try installing a more recent version to see if this solve the error message from AR.

Comment: @MartinSchröder What about the black hyphens, is it an intended behaviour? I would prefer to have all in red personally. The hyphens colour behaviour is also present if textblock is not used.

Comment: This type of color support is a bit "inofficial", it was only added to to copy the xetex feature (https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/41). I don't know if it can be fixed, but you should add an issue to the luaotfload issue tracker.

Comment: The issue will be addressed in the upcoming release of Luaotfload. Also, as @Ulrike-Fischer rightfully pointed out, the font-based colorization is little more than a hack for compatibility. Please consider using a proper colorization package instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s something in between a bug report and a feature request for Luaotfload concerning  borderline supported functionality ;) The next release will come with a fix.

Comment: @phg Is it ok if I simply delete my question? I found an alternative to do what I wanted. Also, before I delete, would it be possible to point me to a better way for "proper colorization package instead". Just need keywords, will be enough. Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien Gosselin leave the question for reference, it’s valid just IMO not appropriate for this site. Regarding colorization perhaps start with the [luacolor](http://ctan.org/pkg/luacolor) package. It’s specifically geared toward the Luatex engine so it should be one of the best options. I’d recommend searching around for other suggestions especially by the crowd that actually do use Latex ;)